# Gitignore Exceptions Not Being Added to Tracking

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I have the following in my .gitignore:

```
*.log
/bower_components/*
/node_modules
!/bower_components/v-accordion
!/node_modules/todomvc-app-css/*
```

I added the last two lines after I installed those components, so that may be the issue, but I cannot tell.

Either way, I would like to track changes to those directories as I am actively customizing them and pushing to production.

However, I cannot seem to get Git to track them.
What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve this?

**Edit:**

Newer version of .gitignore:

```
*.log

/bower_components/**
!/bower_components/v-accordion/
!/bower_components/v-accordion/**

/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-calendar/
!/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-calendar/
!/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-calendar/**

/node_modules/
/node_modules/**
!/node_modules/todomvc-app-css/
!/node_modules/todomvc-app-css/**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I cannot seem to get Git to track them

Simply check with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- node_modules/todomvc-app-css/afile
```

That will confirm the rule in a `.gitignore` which prevents you to track that file.

The rule is simple:

[**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)

You need to exclude folders first before excluding content:

```
*.log

/bower_components/**
!/bower_components/v-accordion/**/
!/bower_components/v-accordion/**

/node_modules/**
/node_modules/todomvc-app-css/**/
!/node_modules/todomvc-app-css/**
```

Comment: I first edited the .gitignore file, then ran the command you suggested. However, when I make changes to the file, and run `git status` it still does not register any changes. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: @MadPhysicist What `git check-ignore -v -- node_modules/todomvc-app-css/afile` (replace '`afile`' appropriately) returns?

Comment: This: `.gitignore:9:!/bower_components/angular-bootstrap-calendar/** bower_components/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/css/angular-bootstrap-calendar.css`
Note, I am using a different file from that of the original question. I edited .gitingore as shown in my edit to the question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist OK, I have edited my answer: you actually want to exclude *all* the subfolders, as in `!/bower_components/v-accordion/**/` (not the final `/**/` at the end). Then you can exclude files.

Comment: What is the difference between `/**` and `/**/`

Comment: @MadPhysicist `/**` is for all files and folders recursively., `/**/` is for folders only (still recursively).As I said, you need to exclude folders first, then files. Try it out. It will work.